# How to click on pseudo-element when testing?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, rspec, capybara, togglebutton

I have a switch / toggle element coming from bootstrap. It works perfectly as expected but I'm having trouble when testing the feature because I don't know how I can click on it:

the toggle is handled by the pseudo-elements :before & :after. I tried many pieces of code to simulate the click on it with capybara but I didn't find a way to achieve it...

Here the snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/ynuf96qe/

[image]

[image]

Anyone has an idea? Thank you!

Sorry for this element, I didn't find a way to bypass the link error from stackoverflow...
`<div></div>`

Comment: Pseudo elements are not a part of the DOM, they don't react to DOM events. What you can do, is to detect the clicked coordinates on the element the pseudo element is attached to. If the coordinates are on the pseudo element area, do what you need, otherwise just ignore the click.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure to figure it out what you want me to do, though. If you have a look to the html snippet, you'll see that the element that handle the pseudo-elements is the label. Problem is: coordinates of it are not above those pseudo-elements.

Comment: I can't see any pseudo elements in your fiddle at all ..?

Comment: There are: if you inspect the HTML of the toggle, you'll see within the label element, the pseudo-elements ::before & ::after

Comment: Yes, but how to click those elements, as they're not visible on the screen? I've added `content` property to the pseudo elements, now they're scattered all over the page. Can you please create a more realistic example code?

Comment: Sorry I think I don't get what you mean :/ For me, the pseudo-elements are visible on the page: I added a picture to show what I mean! Thanks for your help again, it's really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way out even if I don't like it...

I changed the way the toggle is displayed in test environment: it is a simple checkbox that allows me to click on it through Capybara.

It now works fine but I'm aware that is a hack.